# Pyspark: Split a single column with multiple values into separate columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in a dataset which I need to break into multiple columns.

Here is a sample of the column `contextMap_ID1` and that is the result I am looking for.

This code will create the sample (column `contextMap_ID1`) and outcome (the other columns except the second one). The second column explains the logic I expect.

```
dfx = sc.parallelize([
              ("blah blah blah createdTimeStamp=2020-08-11 15:31:37.458 blah blah blah","contains the word 'TimeStamp' >> do not process","","","")
             ,(123456789,"NUMERIC 9 digit Number >> caseId",123456789,"","")
             ,("caseId: 2345678 personId: 87654321","Multiple key value pairs >> New Column(s) with key as column Name",2345678,87654321,"")
             ,("CRON","AlphaNumeric without ':'  >> Do not process","","","")
             ,("ABC9876543210","Alpha-NUMERIC starting with 'ABC' >> New Column","","","ABC9876543210")
            ]).toDF(["contextMap_ID1","Description of rules","caseId","personId","ABC"])
dfx.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Please show your code rather than images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is a chain of `when` conditions based on a list of regex to decide how to handle the row. Then, depending on the logic, you can extract a list of of key value pairs (column name and value).

The logic in the code below may not be exactly what you need (it produces the output you expect though), but the way it is done, you can easily add or modify conditions.

It could look like this

```py
from pyspark.sql.import functions as F

# So let's first define the conditions and the associated logic
transfo=dict()
# List of pairs
transfo['^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s*:\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s*)+$'] = F.split(
    F.regexp_replace(F.col('contextMap_ID1'), "\\s*:\\s*", ":"), "\\s+")
# 9 digit number
transfo['^[0-9]{9}$'] = F.array(F.concat_ws(':',
    F.lit("caseId"),
    F.col("contextMap_ID1")))
# Three letters and a number
transfo['^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]+$'] = F.array(F.concat_ws(':', 
    F.regexp_extract(F.col("contextMap_ID1"), '[A-Z]+', 0),
    F.regexp_extract(F.col("contextMap_ID1"), '[0-9]+', 0 )))

# let's combine the conditions into a chain of when/otherwise.
# the initialization of my_fun is meant to avoid discarding rows
# without key value pairs.
my_fun = F.array(F.lit('caseId'))
for x in transfo:
    my_fun = F.when(F.col('contextMap_ID1').rlike(x),
                    transfo[x]).otherwise(my_fun)
```

Once we prepared the main transformation, we can wrap everything up. We explode the generated key value pairs using `my_fun`, extract them and pivot on the key to generate new columns.

Note that we add an id in case `contextMap_ID1` is not unique. If it is, you may remove the id.

```py
dfx\
    .select('contextMap_ID1', F.monotonically_increasing_id().alias('id'))\
    .select('contextMap_ID1', 'id', F.explode(my_fun).alias("keyvalue"))\
    .withColumn("key", F.split(F.col('keyvalue'), ":").getItem(0))\
    .withColumn("value", F.split(F.col('keyvalue'), ":").getItem(1))\
    .groupBy("id", "contextMap_ID1")\
    .pivot("key")\
    .agg(F.first(F.col('value')))
    .show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------+
|id         |contextMap_ID1                                                        |ABC       |caseId   |personId|
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------+
|34359738368|caseId: 2345678 personId: 87654321                                    |null      |2345678  |87654321|
|25769803776|123456789                                                             |null      |123456789|null    |
|60129542144|ABC9876543210                                                         |9876543210|null     |null    |
|8589934592 |blah blah blah createdTimeStamp=2020-08-11 15:31:37.458 blah blah blah|null      |null     |null    |
|51539607552|CRON                                                                  |null      |null     |null    |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Oli.  This worked perfectly.
The above code gave me a additional column with no name and null values, I had to add a filter to remove empty "keyvalues" right after explode:
df2.withColumn("keyvalue", \explode(split(regexp_replace(df2['contextMap_ID1'], "\\s*:\\s*", ":"), "\\s+")))\
    .filter('keyvalue <> ""')\
    .withColumn("key", split(col('keyvalue'), ":").getItem(0))\
    .withColumn("value", split(col('keyvalue'), ":").getItem(1))\
    .groupBy("timestamp", "message", "contextMap_ID1")\
    .pivot("key")\
    .agg(first(col('value')))\
    .show(truncate=False)

Comment: Glad I could help. If your problem is solved, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Hi Oli,  
The above code worked fine for a file I was testing with one file, however when I exploded it to use the entire dataset for one day's data, we noticed an issue where we had thousands of colums.
The reason is that, if contextMap_ID1 has a value "IOE123456789", we have a new column named "IOE123456789" with value = null

Also, we have thousands of values  where there is just an ID and has not ":", for example:
contextMap_ID1
--------------
55909455
56212949
56271037
56305293

in this case we have columns named as the number with values = null

Comment: Another issue I have is that there is a timestamp stored in this column in the format:

caseId: BaseVersionableJpaEntity [version=10]BaseJpaEntity [createdUserId=Lockbox, updatedUserId=XXX Internal, createdTimeStamp=2019-10-24 20:14:58.182, updatedTimeStamp=2019-11-21 16:16:54.262]

In the above case, the hours minutes and seconds are creating new columns which is an undesirable outcome.
Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: For the first question, what would be the desired behavior. Can you update your question with all the details, sample input and expected output? It would help me understand what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I Modified the post. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The columns have no names?

Comment: My fault.  Fixed the dataframe code in the original post
Also note from my first comment, the filter condition is not showing a few of the original rows.

Comment: I entirely rewrote my answer, let me know what you think

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the answer?